# CSS vertical-align paragraph into div

Tags: html, css

I have a div (with fixed height) with this CSS:

```
.div {
color: white;
font-family: Bahnschrift;
text-align: justify;
vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

As you can see, in this div there are paragraphs vertical aligned at the top. I want to align only the last paragraph (class="lastpar") at the bottom of the div, this is the CSS:

```
.lastpar {
position: relative;
vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

But it doesn't work, could you please help me to align it at the bottom of the div? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertical-align is not intended for aligning block elements.

Use flexbox for this

apply the following rule to the parent

```
div {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

then in another div wrap all elements but the paragraph you want to remain at bottom, and you're all set.